# vb.net mdi application shared dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset, shared, mdi

I have a VB.net MDI app that the child forms use a dataset and a single table. A dozen children means a dozen datasets. Now I would like to compare data, append and merge tables. It would be most convenient to move to a single shared dataset with 12 tables. So far I have not been successful in coding a shared dataset that intellisense will accept. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: It's not really clear how you're having difficulty or what intellisense has to do with it.  If all of the forms need to access a single object, can't they all just access a single object?  Maybe a static property somewhere?  Or some singleton which manages the object?

Answer (score 0):

Create a module in your application that contains the dataset and have the child forms interact with it. Here I was able to get the dataset visible in intellisense.

```
Module Module1
    Private _sharedData As DataSet
    Public Property SharedData As DataSet
        Get
            If (Module1._sharedData Is Nothing) Then
                Module1._sharedData = New DataSet()
            End If
            Return Module1._sharedData
        End Get
        Set(value As DataSet)
            Module1._sharedData = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Module
```

Have your child forms manage their own table in the dataset.

```
Public Class ChildForm

    Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String)
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.Name = Name
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Module1.SharedData.Tables.Add("MyTable" + Me.Name)
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is a test from the MDI Parent.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Shared NextNumber As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim addFrm = New ChildForm(NextNumber.ToString)

        addFrm.MdiParent = Me
        addFrm.Show()

        NextNumber = NextNumber + 1

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        MessageBox.Show(Module1.SharedData.Tables.Count)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm Jimmy, David commented on the question :)